# "Updating status for Apache Tomcat v7.0 at localhost...". java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to run a Spring MVC Application in Eclipse.However,I'm getting the above mentioned  error at regular intervals.Although,One of the Users had posted the answer on the site,it had dependency on Maven.I am not using Maven,Below mentioned is the error

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating status for Apache Tomcat v7.0   
at localhost...". java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Below mentioned are the things that i have tried to rectify the error.

1)Deleted the Server by clicking Double click on the "Apache Tomcat Server 7.0"
   present in the servers window.

2) Installed a New Apache Tomcat Server and tried to associate it with the Project

3)Deleted the .snap file present in "workspace/metadata/com.resources/....." and restarted eclipse.

Any Suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Stack trace for that `IOOBE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, these type of exceptions are due to conflict of librairies.
To confirm that, remove your project and try to restart tomcat and see. If it restarts, then the problem is related to your project dependencies. If your are using maven, go through your dependencies and check your artifactIds to ensure you are getting everything correct.